# Wrong data updated in mysql when function runs first time

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

```
function renew_status($propertyId){
   $code    =   '';
   $code    =   mt_rand(500000, 999999);
   $q   =   "UPDATE `ps_listings` SET 
                             `accessCode` = $code, 
                             `renew`    =   '0' 
                     WHERE `id` =   $propertyId ";
  mysql_query($q) or die(mysql_error());
  $this->db->select('accessCode')->from('ps_listings');
  $this->db->where(array('id' => $propertyId)); 
  $query = $this->db->get();
  $results = $query->result();
      return $results[0]->accessCode;
}
```

I am updating a mysql table through codeigniter function. first time when i access my function it updates wrong number but if i refresh the page correct value is updated.
return $results[0]->accessCode; gives me this code 893195. while in database it saves 997228. Please Help me

Comment: Why are you reading the access code that you just updated from the database again, instead of just returning the value you already have directly? (Maybe that’s also where the problem lies, some kind of database-side caching.)

Comment: i need that accessCode to put on view for some other purpose. i tried this so clear what code passed generated by mt_rand(500000,999999)

Comment: accessCode is bigint in mysql database is that effect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
function renew_status($propertyId){
  $code    =   '';
  $code    =   mt_rand(500000, 999999);
  $data = array('accessCode' => $code, 'renew' => '0');
  $this->db->where('id',$propertyId);
  $this->db->update('ps_listings',$data);

  $this->db->select('accessCode');
  $this->db->where('id',$propertyId); 
  $query = $this->db->get('ps_listings');
  $results = $query->result_array();
  return $results[0]->accessCode;
}
```

Comment: same result, no effect

Comment: accessCode is bigint in mysql database is that effect?

Comment: reduce the values in mt_rand() like mt_rand(5000,6000)

Comment: Thank you serma, your code works just one more thing i added that was check of user logged in or not. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

1) Use mysql_affected_rows for check works update or no. 
2) I think refresh page is wrong way. Use Session for deny double update. 
3) For debugging retrieve and print accessCode before updating, after, and in
   result(UI).

Comment: I perform all these cases, every query returns the code which is randomly generated, but in the database the code is different.

Answer (score 0):

1) is "id" column unique and not null?

2) what does the following code returns :

```
echo count($results);
```

Comment: yes "id" column is unique and not null. its primary key.
echo count($results) return 1

Comment: accessCode is bigint in mysql database is that effect?